# associate and attach not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two models : User and FavoriteUser

My relationship looks like this :

User:

```
public function favorites(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\FavoriteUser', 'user_id');
    }
```

Favorite user:

```
public function favorite_users()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
  }
```

So how can i say something like this:

```
$user->favorites()->associate($user_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two model User and Favorite

and then declare in User:

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Favorite'');
}
```

and in Favorite:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

and then you can do:

```
$user->favorites()->attach($user_id);
```

Comment: `attach()` works for Many to Many Relationships...but this isn't